# 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributes, project

I'm getting an error about `'NoneType' object has no attribute...`. How do I resolve it?

```
def fight(self, pMonstername):
    print ("The fight begin")
    MonInList = self.monsterSearch(pMonstername) 
#at first I have the method "Fight" where i build a temp variable MonInList
#which I declare with the help of the methode "monsterSearch" 

def monsterSearch(self, pMonstername):
    for m in self.monsterList:
        if m.name == pMonstername:
            return m
#in this method I go through step by step through the monsterList, in which 
#are objects of type Monster are stored and pick out those monster which has
#the same name as those I search for and this object should be returned

if self.player.getStrength() > MonInListe.getStrength:
#later I want to compare the strength of the player and the Monster, which i 
#declared before, but then there is the error:
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getStrength'
```

Comment: I pass the mistakes by but the real problems stay the same: How can I verify a temp var as an object?

Answer (score 0):

### The Short Answer

The short answer to this question is that the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getStrength'` suggests that you have `self.player = None` in the `__init__()` of the class that contains your conditional `if self.player.getStrength() > ...`, but it wasn't properly updated to be something else (perhaps an instance of class `Player`?) before the conditional.

There are some other problems and errors that this will trigger, but this is the place where I would start to try to debug things.

### The Long Answer

Another important thing to watch out for is that just because you've included the method in your class doesn't mean it will automatically run. The fact that you are running into the error that you described, and not one of the other errors I think I see in your code, suggests that the methods are either not being called in the correct order to be properly used in your comparison, or are not called at all. This is why I think the Player class was simply not being called correctly.

To give an example, see the code block below. It is a variation of what was provided in the question, and if it is run it will reproduce the problem. First the classes and methods:

```
# The post author mentioned there objects of the type Monster
# stored in a list in the main class. 
# Using the main monster characters from Monsters Inc, 
# below are hastily constructed classes to attempt to reproduce the issue.
class Sully(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "James P. Sullivan"
        self.getStrength = 10



class Player(object):

    def getStrength(self):
        return 100


class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.monsterList = [Sully]
        self.player = None


    def fight(self, pMonstername):
        #at first I have the method "Fight" where i build a temp variable MonInList
        #which I declare with the help of the methode "monsterSearch" 
        print ("The fight begin")
        MonInList = self.monsterSearch(pMonstername) 

    def monsterSearch(self, pMonstername):
        #in this method I go through step by step through the monsterList, in which 
        #are objects of type Monster are stored and pick out those monster which has
        #the same name as those I search for and this object should be returned
        for m in self.monsterList:
            if m.name == pMonstername:
                return m

    def compareStrength(self):

        #later I want to compare the strength of the player and the Monster, which i 
        #declared before, but then there is the error:
        if self.player.getStrength() > MonInListe.getStrength:
            print("Success!")
            # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getStrength'
```

Next, let's create an instance of SomeClass and then run the `compareStrength` method:

```
s = SomeClass()
s.compareStrength()
```

The result is this error, the stack provided in full:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-bfa22232a4a7> in <module>()
      1 s = SomeClass()
----> 2 s.compareStrength()

<ipython-input-70-3a4fe2cd3c3c> in compareStrength(self)
     42         #later I want to compare the strength of the player and the Monster, which i
     43         #declared before, but then there is the error:
---> 44         if self.player.getStrength() > MonInListe.getStrength:
     45             print("Success!")
     46             # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getStrength'

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getStrength'
```

What's interesting about this is that this should NOT have been the first error that was triggered. I would have expected this error instead:

```
The fight begin
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-5009b509291a> in <module>()
      1 s = SomeClass()
----> 2 s.fight("James P. Sullivan")
      3 s.compareStrength()

<ipython-input-77-13d18f4abe98> in fight(self, pMonstername)
     29         #which I declare with the help of the methode "monsterSearch"
     30         print ("The fight begin")
---> 31         MonInList = self.monsterSearch(pMonstername)
     32 
     33     def monsterSearch(self, pMonstername):

<ipython-input-77-13d18f4abe98> in monsterSearch(self, pMonstername)
     36         #the same name as those I search for and this object should be returned
     37         for m in self.monsterList:
---> 38             if m.name == pMonstername:
     39                 return m
     40 

AttributeError: type object 'Sully' has no attribute 'name'
```

...which would be caused by running this code:

```
s = SomeClass()
s.fight("James P. Sullivan")
s.compareStrength()
```

I think `s.fight()` should have been called and triggered this error because otherwise the `MonInList` would not be correct when we run `compareStrength()`. It's for this reason that I think simply reviewing the order in which the methods are being called will fix the main issue in the question, which is why I included it here (even though it seems tangential).

Oh, and by the way, the fix for the latest issue described would be to change the line `if m.name == pMonstername:` to `if m().name == pMonstername:`

Hope that helps!

Comment: `getStrength` is a function object - it doesn't make sense in this context to say that it "has not yet been populated with a value." And the thing that is `None` here is `self.player`.

Comment: def getStrength(self):
        self.strength = self.power
        return self.strength

Comment: ah and sorry the last getStrength should have been a method i correct it

Comment: Excellent, thanks for confirming and correcting that the last getStrength should have been a method. I apologize if my answer was poorly worded as @TigerhawkT3 corrected, but that was the main point I was trying to make so I'm glad that made sense. I'll update and adjust my answer accordingly

Comment: This answer still isn't helpful and doesn't make sense. Further, if you want to ask for clarification about a question, please leave it as a comment, not an answer (as answers should actually answer the question). You will be able to leave comments once you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Thanks @TigerhawkT3 for the feedback, I will certainly keep it in mind going forward. I rewrote my answer entirely to attempt to answer the question as best as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so it seems that your object 'MonInListe' has not been instantiated before being used. It then gets to be 'None' and effectively has no attribute.
You should check elsewhere in your code (not in the shown part of it here) for the correct instantiation of this object 'MonInListe'.
The origin of the error you are encountering is definitively not contained in the part of the code you expose here.

Comment: `None` isn't the same as "was never instantiated."

Comment: how do i instantiate it? I only want that this temp variable get the same attributes like the "real" object which is in the MonInList. Like a copy. So that they get the same access to the methods of the class monster

Comment: So, now that you have corrected your shown code, you should still get the same error code. As an attribute, getStrength is a function. Nevertheless, is this error raised because of self.player or because of MoninListe? Just to know it, try to print each of these values on two different lines:

    print self.player.getStrength(), and 
    print MonInListe.getStrength()

. You will then know what is the object that is raising the error.

Comment: It's the MonInListe that makes the problem

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you want to ask for clarification on a question, please do so with a comment, not in an answer (answers should answer the question). You will be able to leave a comment once you have sufficient reputation.